# Getting InvalidOperationException

Tags: vb.net, invalidoperationexception

The program functioned perfectly. When I stopped it and restarted it, it came up with the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
HResult=-2146233079
Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
Source=WorkFlowConfig
```

StackTrace:

```
   at WorkFlowConfig.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   ErrorCode=-2146824584
   HelpLink=C:\Windows\HELP\ADO270.CHM#1240653
   HResult=-2146824584
   Message=Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
   Source=ADODB.Recordset
   StackTrace:
        at ADODB._Recordset.Close()
        at WorkFlowConfig.frm_WF_Config.ListWF() in C:\MBS Integration\WorkFlow\frm_WF_Config.vb:line 392
        at WorkFlowConfig.frm_WF_Config.chkActiveHistoryOnly_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\MBS Integration\WorkFlow\frm_WF_Config.vb:line 341
        at System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox.OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox.set_CheckState(CheckState value)
        at System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox.set_Checked(Boolean value)
        at WorkFlowConfig.frm_WF_Config.InitializeComponent() in C:\MBS Integration\WorkFlow\frm_WF_Config.Designer.vb:line 889
        at WorkFlowConfig.frm_WF_Config..ctor()
   InnerException:
```

This message is happens in the Application.Designer.vb on the following line:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = Global.WorkFlowConfig.frm_WF_Config
    End Sub
```

Where do I start to look?

Comment: something in your start up procedures is causing a `chkActiveHistoryOnly_CheckedChanged` event which does something else which is not legal yet

Comment: It looks like it has something to with a closed 'database connection' object, invalid ADO parameter possibly, maybe the connection string...  Google 2146824584 without the (-) and you'll see quite a bit of info related to the error you're seeing